# how to check memory continuously when the application is running in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have **windows application** in that I am opening a form2 from form1. At the same time, i want to check the **memory used by the application all the time, continuously** ... 
can any one help how to monitor applications memory programatically...

also, my application is consists of private DLL and private grids which leads to use more memory... I tried several methods like Dispose() and garbage collector and disposing the classes used for private grid.

Thannks

Comment: Share your code and error.

Comment: I am not getting error .. application is working fine... Want to stop application when it is reached certain limit. Bcoz, my application is getting crashed after a that limit...

Comment: This kind of behavior is not what you should call "working fine".

Comment: I feel like Its working better....means faster,  Apart from the memory consuming... Please suggest the better way to reduce the private DLL consuming memory....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Visual Studio Profiler to monitor your application and search for memory leaks/performance issues. It will give you an extensive report based on the sampling technique you choose.

See [MSDN Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can measure three types of memory: private memory, physical memory, virtual memory

```
 long PhysicalMemory = Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / 1024;
 long virtualMemory = Process.GetCurrentProcess().VirtualMemorySize64 / 1024;
 var PM = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
 long privateMemory=PM.RawValue / 1024
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Will it calculate continuously as long as my application is running...!!!  To my knowledge , it work for one time..

Comment: it will work for one time.. you'll have to use loop or another thread which will continous monitor it..

Comment: Could you please eloborate how to proceed with thead...will backgroudworker will do this.?

Comment: you can use Multithreading one of the thread would call above code in a loop in a background worker process (otherwise your application will hang). Other way would be create a separate application and call that application from your main application and it will record memory consumption of your main application using  Process.GetProcessesByName("Name of process") instead of Process.GetCurrentProcess() in the above code

Comment: You could use the tick event of a timer for refreshing the value each second. Don't think that this will freeze your application and it's far more simple.